# Как использовать полученный stream в теге video MinioJS

Tags: javascript

```
minioClient.getObject("busket", "name.mp4", function(
  err,
  stream
) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log("stream", stream);
  stream.on("data", function(chunk) {
    size += chunk.length;
  });
  stream.on("end", function() {
    console.log("End. Total size = " + size);
  });
  stream.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
});

let player = document.getElementById("introduction");
```

Как использовать полученный `stream` в `player`?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо огромное за ответ. Но мне кажется тут будет что то другое. Вот похожий ответ нашел на просторах интернета. Но он тоже не работает.(((

function startVideo() {
player = document.getElementById("player")

```
const mediaSource = new MediaSource()
const url = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource)

player.src = url

mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen)
```

}

async function sourceOpen() {
let mediaSource = this

```
const videoSourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"')

let fetchResult = await fetch(`/asset/video/${videoLocation}`)
let videoData = await fetchResult.arrayBuffer()

videoSourceBuffer.appendBuffer(videoData)
```

}